# Came across an unknown vector notation in a practice test. What do the 2 vertical arrows between a pair of vectors denote?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors

$$\overrightarrow a\uparrow\uparrow\overrightarrow b$$

Could someone please explain what the 2 vertical arrow *between* a pair of vectors represent? I could not find any explanation online.

I found the notation in a question from my college test.

[Vector question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWduV.png)

Comment: Context, please.

Comment: It would help if you explain where you came across this. For example, was it in a particular textbook? What is a sentence that uses this notation?

Comment: Sure. Added the question from my college test where I found the unknown notation.

Comment: I would guess it means that the vectors $\overrightarrow a$ and $\overrightarrow b$ are parallel/ colinear

Comment: This is not standard notation but “parallel” is my best guess. It occurred to me that this could be a joke on the part of the test writers, to see if anyone chooses a nonsensical answer.

Comment: $a || b$ is standard notation for parallel line segments, so one could guess that your symbols means parallel vectors pointing in the same direction (ie. parallel with positive coefficient of similarity). It's just a guess though.